# A word to convey "to make something relevant'

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that could convey the meaning of '**to make something relevant**'? I am talking in the context of adapting and utilising certain art theories (contemporary art and postmodernism, mainly) which originated in Western sphere and were gradually adapted and utilisied here in Indonesia. By relevance, I also imply the framing and contextualisation.

Comment: The 'Greetings ... solicitis' and 'Regards', although polite, aren't really necessary. You can check what's on topic [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and look at the [meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com) for more help with this.

Comment: We have strange customs here -- we like people to be polite, but not bother with the little politenesses of polite conversation.  You have a fine question.  +1.  You want a single word, and the only thing I can think of (yet) is a phrase:  "Bring into the mainstream"

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps ***contemporize*** would fit.

> to give a modern or contemporary character or setting to; update:
>
> > *The new production of* Romeo and Juliet ***contemporizes*** *it as the love of two modern teenagers in a Chicago high school.*
>
> <sub>[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/contemporize)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

***Bring into the mainstream***  This isn't a single word, which the OP asked for, but I offer it anyway.

In the OP's context:

> I am talking about ***bringing into the mainstream*** of Indonesian
>   culture certain art theories (contemporary art and postmodernism,
>   mainly) which originated in the Western sphere.

The problem I have with my answer is not that is a phrase, but that I don't know if these art theories are being brought into the mainstream, or will remain only minor tributaries, even among the avant-garde of Indonesia.

mainstream, [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mainstream)

> The ideas, attitudes, or activities that are shared by most people and
>   regarded as normal or conventional